# Xamarin.Forms: Tiny icons are getting cut ever so slightly when size is set with grid value

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

this is a simple grid with a tiny button in it:

```
    <!--ReverseButton-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" RowSpacing="0" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ImageButton
                Source="btn_reversed_unpressed"
                x:Name="btn_reverse_list_mainmenu"
                BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Clicked="ReverseListForSwipeView"
            />
        </Grid>
```

The size of this Row (row 1) is set here:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.17*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="4.5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I set the value to 0.17* to have the button always be very tiny. If i would set the row to "auto" the icon would become much bigger (since the source image is bigger in size)

If I make the size to, lets say 0.25* instead of 0.17* the row and therefore the button both get bigger and everything is fine. (Except now it is too big)

But with size 0.17* it is just about right... Well except for this:

[image]

It is quite hard to see, but the icon at the bottom is cut of slightly. The border is not as big as it is on the top.

This I have noticed quite some time now. 
I tried setting the rowspacing to 0 or even negative values, but nothing worked.

Why is the icon cut off. 
The top part isnt cut and both parts (top and bottom) touch the row end and beginning pixel perfect.

Comment: Why don't you set the `HeightRequest` of the `ImageButton` to the size you want the icon to be and then just set the row height to `Auto` and let the layout manager do the rest?

Comment: @CodingLumis it is my understanding, that the values in height request are actually pixels. So depending on the screen size, the icons would be in different sizes. But using values in rows are percentages. Therefore, every icon would be the right size regardless of the phone

Comment: The numbers are density-independent pixels in Xamarin Forms so they will be the same size on different screen densities. If you want them to be a particular proportion of the screen space then you will have to override `OnSizeAllocated` and use the width and height of the screen to calculate the sizes you want and then assign the height values there.

Answer (score 0):

An answer based on my comment above. I suggest setting the HeightRequest of the ImageButton to the size you want the icon to be and then just set the row height to Auto and let the layout manager do the rest. See my example where I create a `Grid` with 3 rows set to Auto size and then just use the `HeightRequest` property to have it draw at the correct size. I left the grey background of the button in so you can see how the row sizes dynamically.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ImageButton Source="ic_email_dark"
                     Aspect="AspectFit"
                     HeightRequest="50"
                     HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Grid.Row="0" />

        <ImageButton Source="ic_email_dark"
                     Aspect="AspectFit"
                     HeightRequest="75"
                     HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Grid.Row="1" />

        <ImageButton Source="ic_email_dark"
                     Aspect="AspectFit"
                     HeightRequest="100"
                     HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     Grid.Row="2" />

    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Gives the following:

[image]

Comment: Please see my comment underneath your comment :)